# Google crawling mobile page for my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I am using css media queries for my site for desktop as well for mobiles but google crawls only mobile css and mobile site content.But i want google to crawl desktop site css and desktop content.
following are the media queries for css being used
for mobile

```
@media only screen and  (max-width:320px)
```

for desktop and laptops

```
@media only screen and  (min-width:1100px)
```

meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Currently google crawls only mobile css media query and read the mobile content.But i want it to read desktop css and crawl desktop site content..
How can i do that,please help me people....

Comment: Google is really only interested in content. You can't really hide content from Google if it's in your HTML.

Comment: but then,why keywords which are there in my desktop site are not read by google,but mobile site keywords are read.what can be the reason.

Comment: `why keywords which are there in my desktop site are not read by google` How do you know?